# When importing a csv file into Excel text is converted to number

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing a CSV file into an Excel 2010 spreadsheet using something like this:

```
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myFile, ReadOnly:=True, Notify:=False)
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
 Set rRng = ws.Range("A" & CStr(iFirstDataRow) & ":" & "G" & CStr(iLastRow))
 rRng.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
 'copy file on sheet ws1
 ws1.Cells.Clear
 rRng.Copy ws1.Cells(1, 1)
```

the problem is that one of the columns is containing revision numbers that appear as follows in the CSV file:

```
0.0
1.0
2.2
2.20
```

After the import I get:

```
0
1
2.2
2.2
```

because text has been converted to numbers.

How can I stop this?

Thank you,
M.R.

Update:

using Opentext method does not work either:

```
 Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFile, Origin:=xlWindows, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlMDYFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat))
```

For some reason FieldInfo parameter is ignored

Comment: Record a macro while opening the file using the Data >> From Text menu item.  That allows you to specify the datatype for specific columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim, I recorded the macro, it seems I'l have to use a different syntax than Workbooks.Open

Comment: Set up the Data from text properly until that is working as expected (see [www.jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp) for some pointers). Then just refresh the connection to get new data.

Comment: Thank you jkpieterse. The link you provided relates to manually importing data, however (as Tim Williams also suggested, see answer above), I recorded a macro and my problem is now resolved!

Comment: Great, I used you method and it works!

Comment: My point is that you only need VBA code to either change the file if you don't want to browse for it, or to do the refresh automatically. Setting up the connection to the csv is a one-time process which requires no VBA at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.OpenText
```

with appropriate parameters to define the revision number field as *String*.  See:

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried OpenText method but for some reason FieldInfo parameter that specifies the data type is ignored, regardless what value I enter

Comment: @M.R.  Please update your original question with your current code.

Comment: .OpenText Filename:=sFile, Origin:=xlWindows,     StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, 
            Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, 
            Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, xlMDYFormat), Array(2, xlTextFormat))